# Flask　記事の編集／DBへ反映が行われない

Tags: python, python3, sqlite, flask

Flask、SQLiteでFlaskの学習を行っております。
def update()で記事の編集処理を記載していますが、
記事を編集し、changeボタンを押すと、404エラー画面が表示され
DBにも変更内容が反映されていません。

昨日から、何回も書き直し、見直しを行っていますが、
下記コードで、どこが間違っているのか見当がつかない状況です。
どなたかご教示お願い致します。

その他、create、deleteの処理は問題なくできております。

```html
<!-- index.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Top</h1>

{% for post in posts %}
<h2>タイトル： {{post.title}}</h2>
<p>期限： {{post.due.date()}}</p>

<a href="detail/{{ post.id }}" role="button">詳細</a>
<a href="update/{{ post.id }}" role="button">変更</a>
<a href="delete/{{ post.id }}" role="button">削除</a>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

```py
# app.py

from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
URI = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    detail = db.Column(db.String(100))
    due = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        posts = Post.query.all()
        return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
    else:
        title = request.form.get('title')
        detail = request.form.get('detail')
        due = request.form.get('due')

        due = datetime.strptime(due, '%Y-%m-%d')

        new_post = Post(title=title, detail=detail, due=due)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect('/')

@app.route('/create')
def create():
    return render_template('create.html')


@app.route('/detail/<int:id>')
def read(id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)
    return render_template('detail.html', post=post)


@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('update.html', post=post)
    else:
        post.title = request.form.get('title')
        post.detail = request.form.get('detail')
        post.due = datetime.strptime(request.form.get('due'), '%Y-%m-%d')

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect('/')

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)

    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!-- update.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="update/{{ post.id }}" method="POST">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ post.title }}">
    <label for="detail">Detail</label>
    <input type="text" name="detail" value="{{ post.detail }}">
    <label for="due">Due</label>
    <input type="date" name="due" value="{{ post.due.date() }}" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「change」ボタン押下後
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: （Postmanを使って）直接/detail/<id>にPOSTする分にはエラーもなくDBも更新もきちんとされています．update.htmlの記載があるとエラーの原因が分かるかもしれません

Comment: >update.htmlの記載があるとエラーの原因が分かるかもしれません　update.htmlは本文に記載しております。コードではなく、画面でしょうか？

Comment: update.htmlのformのactionが/updateではなくupdate(頭のスラッシュがない)で始まってるせいじゃないですかね。
「change」ボタン押下後のURLみると/update/updateとupdateが2重になってますし。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、update.htmlのactionをaction="/update/{{ post.id }}"とすることでできました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご指摘の通り、update.htmlのactionをaction="/update/{{ post.id }}"とすることでできました。